# Java test class that make connection to db

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, junit

I have Customer class that make connection to db and save data to mysql. I use tomcat7 and mysql. I want to test this class. I have this method:

```
public CustomerData findById(int customerId) throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    CustomerData customer = null;

    try {
        String sql = "SELECT id, status, username, email, age, country, city, is_hidden FROM "
                + TABLE + " WHERE  id = ?";

        conn = DBManager.getConnection();
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        stmt.setInt(1, customerId);

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {
            customer = new CustomerData(rs.getInt(1), rs.getInt(2),
                    rs.getString(3), null, rs.getString(4), rs.getInt(5),
                    String.valueOf(rs.getInt(6)), String.valueOf(rs
                            .getInt(7)), 0, rs.getInt(8));
        }

        return customer;
    } finally {
        closeConnection(conn, stmt);
    }
}
```

How can I test it?

Comment: What do you want to test? There is hardly any logic in there.

Comment: I want to test sql syntax and returned data

Comment: if you want to test connection, you should test the DBManager. If you want to test CustomerData.findById and if you want to write a unit test, you should use mock object.

Comment: In this case, maybe mocking out the database connection (with a fake one that asserts the SQL string and returns a pre-arranged result set) would work. You'd need to make your DBManager support that, though.

Comment: I want to test CustomerData.findById. what I should mock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test it just like you want to, i would recommend you create a seperate database though, seperating production and test data.

You should check out the article from [dallaway](http://www.dallaway.com/acad/dbunit.html), which is absolutely brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

you should have a db test with prepopulated data. You can call `findById` with a fixed customerId anche check the result against a some constants.
Suppose you have a customer on test db with name "Test" registrationDate "10/10/2010" and Id 1
you could end with something like

```
CustomerData customer = yourclass.findById(1);
Assert.assertNotNull(customer);
Assert.assertEquals(customer.getId(),1);
Assert.assertEquals(customer.getName(),"Test");
Assert.assertEquals(customer.getRegistrationDate(),"10/10/2010");
```

where Assert class is one vailable from Junit o TestNG or you testing framework.